# Django REST framework authentication does not work with Class based view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using DRF (3.12.4) with SimpleJWT for authentication. It is working with function based view but not working with Class based view. For Class based view, there is no effect and the request passed without authentication.
Here is my function based view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def test_function_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({"message": "test ok"}, safe=False, status=200)
```

Here is my class based view

```
class TestClassView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(request):
        return JsonResponse({"message": "post ok"}, safe=False, status=200)
    def get(request):
        return JsonResponse({"message": "get ok"}, safe=False, status=200)
```

Settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

URLs

```
path('api/v1/agents/performancetest/testclass', TestClassView.post),
path('api/v1/agents/performancetest/testfunction', test_function_view),
```

In class based view, the authentication made no effect, so when send GET request without authentication, it passed, and for POST request, it got CRSF error because of no authentication.

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/v1/agents/performancetest/testclass
HTTP POST /api/v1/agents/performancetest/testclass 403 [0.02, 127.0.0.1:59664]
HTTP GET /api/v1/agents/performancetest/testclass 200 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:59664]
```

Is there anything I missed here or any clue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
class TestClassView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({"message": "post ok"}, safe=False, status=200)
    def get(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({"message": "get ok"}, safe=False, status=200)
```

and check you are passing jwt in your api request

Comment: It looks the same as what I'm having now. And even I pass jwt or not, it has no effect.

Comment: Nope...check carefully. you have missed self in your methods